# Not Receiving SMS in Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I need to fetch SMS Response sent from Twilio using web hook using Twilio trial account credentials. In that, generated number is from **US**. And sms is sending from **India** number. And when message is sent back to Twilio that is not shows in incoming messages and not call the webhook url also.

I created app in `twiml`. And set webhook url in that also. But doesn't work.

For web hook I am using ngrok so in my local server so I can get data.

Any one have idea what is wrong I am doing.

**EDITED**

I have created testing twilio account. Generated number and the generated number is from US. I have set up webhook url in manage numbers.
[image]

URL is generated from ngrok so It can be used outside my network.

I have setup Twiml App also. And webhook url is also set there.
[image]

I am sending one programmable message from my node api. And that was working fine. User is getting programmable message but when user reply to that message it should call my webhook url. But it not calling my webhook url and also it not showing in my incoming message.
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Without seeing some of your code, and a better description of what `doesn't work` actually means, no, nobody is likely to have any idea what you are doing wrong.  For tips on formulating your question, check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Don'tPanic please check my Question. I Edited my question.

Comment: Open a support ticket with all the details, something isn't correct if the logs aren't showing a response - https://www.twilio.com/console/support/tickets/create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are struggling with this,
As of now Twilio not supports 2-way messaging in India.

Please refer this for more details.

[Twilio Guidelines for India](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/in/sms)